# Get ref from connected redux component withStyles

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have this export of a working component:

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, actions,
    null, { withRef: true, forwardRef: true }
  )(withTheme()(withStyles(styles)(MainMenu)));
```

And its call:

```
<MainMenu 
  ref={(connectedMenu) => this.menuRef = connectedMenu.getWrappedInstance()} 
  user={user} 
/>
```

I've expected to get a MainMenu ref, but I keep getting WithTheme object instead.

I've also tried to get through innerRef, but got the following errors:

```
TypeError: connectedMenu.getWrappedInstance is not a function
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWrappedInstance' of null
```

Before all of that I've tried that `React.createRef()` format, but it didn't worked.

How do I get this ref?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using v4 of Material-UI, your syntax for `withTheme` is incorrect. In v4 the first set of parentheses [was removed](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#styles).

Instead of

```
withTheme()(YourComponent)
```

you should have

```
withTheme(YourComponent)
```

Below is code from a modified version of the [react-redux todo list tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial) that shows the correct syntax. I've included here the two files that I changed (TodoList.js and TodoApp.js), but the sandbox is a fully working example.

In `TodoApp`, I use the ref on `TodoList` to get and display its height. The displayed height will only get updated if `TodoApp` re-renders, so I've included a button to trigger a re-render. If you add a couple todos to the todo list, and then click the re-render button, you will see that the new height of the list is displayed (showing that the ref is fully working).

In `TodoList`, I'm using `withStyles` to add a blue border around the todo list to show that `withStyles` is working, and I'm displaying the primary color from the theme to show that `withTheme` is working.

`TodoList.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Todo from "./Todo";
import { getTodosByVisibilityFilter } from "../redux/selectors";
import { withStyles, withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";

const styles = {
  list: {
    border: "1px solid blue"
  }
};
const TodoList = React.forwardRef(({ todos, theme, classes }, ref) => (
  <>
    <div>theme.palette.primary.main: {theme.palette.primary.main}</div>
    <ul ref={ref} className={clsx("todo-list", classes.list)}>
      {todos && todos.length
        ? todos.map((todo, index) => {
            return <Todo key={`todo-${todo.id}`} todo={todo} />;
          })
        : "No todos, yay!"}
    </ul>
  </>
));

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { visibilityFilter } = state;
  const todos = getTodosByVisibilityFilter(state, visibilityFilter);
  return { todos };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  { forwardRef: true }
)(withTheme(withStyles(styles)(TodoList)));
```

`TodoApp.js`

```
import React from "react";
import AddTodo from "./components/AddTodo";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import VisibilityFilters from "./components/VisibilityFilters";
import "./styles.css";

export default function TodoApp() {
  const [renderIndex, incrementRenderIndex] = React.useReducer(
    prevRenderIndex => prevRenderIndex + 1,
    0
  );
  const todoListRef = React.useRef();
  const heightDisplayRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (todoListRef.current && heightDisplayRef.current) {
      heightDisplayRef.current.innerHTML = ` (height: ${
        todoListRef.current.offsetHeight
      })`;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="todo-app">
      <h1>
        Todo List
        <span ref={heightDisplayRef} />
      </h1>
      <AddTodo />
      <TodoList ref={todoListRef} />
      <VisibilityFilters />
      <button onClick={incrementRenderIndex}>
        Trigger re-render of TodoApp
      </button>
      <div>Render Index: {renderIndex}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Todo App with Redux]