# Material ui v4 withTheme() does not work with redux compose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

Migrating from v3 to v4.

When using withTheme with compose to provide child components with theme props I get an error

```
export default compose(
    connect,
    withTheme(),
    withStyles(styles)
)(SearchWrapper);
```

> You are calling withTheme(Component) with an undefined component. You
> may have forgotten to import it.

However, when using connect only without relying on compose, I do not get the above error

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(withTheme(withStyles(styles)(SearchWrapper)));
```

How can I retain the compose(...) hierarchy of adding functions.

Comment: You need to remove the parentheses on `withTheme` (see https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#styles).

Comment: tnx @RyanCogswell, I believe that I can go with { withTheme: true } inside withStyles if they exist in composition, what is the preferred way?

Comment: I don't typically use either. I use `useTheme` inside the component that needs it, rather than having the theme injected as a prop.

Comment: I see, seems that hooks are taking over slowly, this v3 to v4 is the worst thing ever experienced so far, If you want to leave an answer for some points go ahead..

Comment: If you want to upvote [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191025/get-ref-from-connected-redux-component-withstyles/57206665#57206665), then I'll just mark this as a duplicate (I can't mark this as a duplicate if the other answer isn't either accepted or upvoted). Your case is a slightly different manifestation of the problem, but same root cause.